# MODIS batch rename

Tags: bash, rename

I have a large set of MODIS files named as following by the day of the year.

```
MOD11B1.A2000065.h24v05.005.2007176161243.hdf
```

I want to rename these files using a Linux shell or anything else such that the file name becomes

```
MOD11B.AYYYY.MM.DD
```

Comment: Could you explain the original file name format? Where are located YYYY, MM and DD?

Comment: You should give more details about other possible formats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to http://modis-atmos.gsfc.nasa.gov/products_filename.html, you file name format is:

```
MOD11B1.A2000065.h24v05.005.2007176161243.hdf
MOD...  A.......
         YYYYDDD
```

Here is a simple script that do the job (I think):

```
#!/bin/bash
yyyymmdd () { date -d "$1-01-01 +$2 days -1 day" "+%Y.%m.%d"; }

for f in MOD*.hdf; do
    YYYY=${f:9:4}
    DDD=${f:13:3}

    OUT="${f/.*/}".A$(yyyymmdd $YYYY $DDD)

    mv "$f" "$OUT"
done
```

The key part is to convert from `YYYYDDD` to `YYYY.MM.DD`. I used a function based on that previous answer: https://superuser.com/a/232106/224101

Otherwise, this is a simple loop over your `MOD*.hdf` files.